# Where do the point coordinates come from in touchesEnded?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

The touchesEnded event is supposed to signal that the finger, which caused a touch event before, has just stopped touching the screen. Nevertheless, it still contains touch location coordinates. Where do they come from? The last touch position on the screen should have been in the last touchesMoved event before, but the coordinates in touchesEnded are different from those. Are they extrapolated? Why does iOS supply these coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS only delivers touch events to your app at most 60 times per second (in sync with screen refreshes).  If a touch both moves and ends between two consecutive screen refreshes, the touch-ended event's location will be the location last reported by the hardware before it reported that the touch ended.

Comment: The distance between two timesteps is 0.015625 sec, which tells me that the digitizer scans the touchpad with 64 Hz. It also tells me that the touch events are not synchronized with the screen refresh rate, but are the actual measurements of the Broadcomm hardware which reads out the touchscreen. Your answer suggests that iOS does some processing in the background and hands the events down at a reduced rate, and some delay. Right or wrong?

Comment: In my experimentation, although there was some jitter in the timestamps, I got only 60 updates per second.  Perhaps things have changed since I investigated this.  I looked into it a couple of years ago.

Comment: I did my testing on a two year old iPad (MC705FD/A) and a new iPad air (MD788FD/A), both running iOS7. And all I took is the time difference between two timestamps. Given that the touchscreen has 39 electrodes which receive 400 µs pulses for the touch measurement each, the 64 Hz make eminently sense. The digitizer did not change much over the years (for all what I know), so I would assume that your measurements should still be valid. And given that multitouch events have the same touch ID for the single fingers, some background processing must take place. Maybe iOS7 reports them differently.